# REST returning right responses

Tags: rest

I have an API that allows clients to post Request messages via a uri: [url]/Request

```
The Request message is xml:
<Request>
    <Source>1234</Source>
    <Destination>5551111</Destination>
    <Message>Hello</Message>
</Request>

The response message is
<Response>
    <Id>2589</Id>
    <Status>Stored</Status>
</Response>
```

Is it correct, in the REST sense for the service located at /Request to return in the HTTP Response a Response message?
Or, should the /Request post return a url to something like

```
/Response?MessageId=2589
```

where a Response messsage is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP specification has this to say about the `POST` request:

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header (see section 14.30).

So, technically, if an entity is included in the POST response it should describe the status of the request. What constitutes the `status of the request` though, is entirely up to the implementor. Most large implementation will return a representation of the newly created resource to indicate 'Success', and an error message to indicate 'Failure'. In any case, you will want to set the `Location` header of the response to be the URI of the newly created resource.